# JS незаметный скролл чата вниз

Tags: javascript, html, css

При заходе в чат, естественно нужно проскроллить вниз, дабы показать последние сообщения. Я делаю это так:

```
function elemscrolltop(elem) {
    msgboard = document.getElementById(elem);
    msgboard.scrollTop = msgboard.scrollHeight;
}
```

Но дело в том, что скролл происходит рывком заметным на глаз, а хотелось бы сделать это прозрачно, как к примеру в ВК, зашел диалог, и он открылся в самом низу. Не подскажете, как это делается?

Comment: Вроде как, в мобильной версии вк div добавляется сверху поэтому прокручивания, как такового не нужно. Сообщение само прилетает в место последнего, сдвигая остальные вниз. Значит, ваш случай - это когда поле ввода внизу, и сообщения читаются снизу вверх?

Comment: Вы тут заврались, в компьютерной версии ВК я чётко вижу рывок :)